# Removing duplicate rows in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 27949 rows & 7 columns & the first few rows look like below
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pipf.png

Task:
In the dataframe I have a 'title' column which has many duplicate titles which I want to remove *(duplicate title:almost all the title is same except for 1 or 2 words)*. 
Pseudo code:
I want to check the 1st row with all other rows & if any of these is a duplicate I want to remove it. Then I want to check the 2nd row with all other rows & if any of these is a duplicate I want to remove it - similarly with all rows i.e. i = 1st line to last line j = i+1 to last line.
My code:

```
for i in range(0,27950):
    for j in range(1,27950):
        a = data_sorted['title'].iloc[i].split()
        b = data_sorted['title'].iloc[j].split()
        if len(a)-len(b)<=2:
            data_sorted.drop(b)
            j=j
        else:
            j+=1
    i+=1
```

Error:
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Can anyone please help me out with my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does a duplicate title mean a duplicated row? because if the title is duplicated but not the row, it can leads to issues.

Comment: Anyway the reason why you are getting positional index error is because you have tried to drop the element in the loop, setting the j=j will not reduce the range of index that you will be looping through.

Comment: i added j=j bcoz if when the row at j(i+1) is dropped then the next row after j now becomes the jth row

Comment: but your j=j will have no effect, and there is no need for you do to j+=1 and i+=1, in python, the increment in for-loop is automatic. so what you are doing is in fact i+=2 and j+=2 in each iteration. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: another problem with your code is that it compares the number of words in each title, it does not compare the spelling of the words. so a title like "Hello World" is the same as "Good Morning".

Comment: Can you offer a sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: Seems a bit strange to dynamically drop rows of a `DataFrame`, since `DataFrame`s are mostly append-only data structures when I use them. Would use `group_by` and `apply` to create a new `DataFrame` in dedup applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach:

Build a difference matrix of your title, where the i,j element will represent the word difference between i'th and j'th title.

Like so:

```
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import product

    l = list(data_sorted['title'])

    def diff_words(text_1, text_2):
        # return the number of different words between two texts
        words_1 = text_1.split()
        words_2 = text_2.split()
        diff = max(len(words_1),len(words_2))-len(np.intersect1d(words_1, words_2))
        return diff


    differences = [diff_words(i,j) for i,j in product(l,l)]
    # differences: a flat matrix integers where the i,j element is the word difference between titles i and j
```